# How do I turn off erroneous float/long error messages from gcc

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

I recently was making a change to to our codebase from float to long for some variables, and discovered that there were no error messages generated by the compiler in areas I knew were still wrong. This led me to add -Wconversion to the compiler flags. But, oops, this leads to some spurious error messages.  In the snippet below, I get errors as noted. What can I do to supress this message on a case-by-case basis, or coax gcc into being smarter about this? The -Wconversion flag generates thousands of warnings in our code base. Am I going to have to examine them all?  Grrr.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void
takes_a_float  ( float some_num ) {
    printf("float Hello %f\n", some_num );
}
int
main (int argc, char **argv)  {
    float my_boat = 1.0f;
    takes_a_float (  my_boat );
    exit (0);
}

gcc -Wconversion foo.c
foo.c: In function `main':
foo.c:13: warning: passing arg 1 of `takes_a_float' as `float' rather than `double' due to prototype

 $ gcc -v
Reading specs from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.6/specs
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr   /share/info --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --disable-checking --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-java-awt=gtk --host=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-10)
```

**EDIT**

As pointed out by John Millikin, the -Wconversion flag is working 'as designed'. (I had thought it was about type-conversion, but it turns out it's about converting really old C-style programs to ISO-standard C. Darn.  A reading of the gcc warning
documentation page for my version of gcc doesn't give me hope, but in any event, what I really want is some other warning flag to enable that will warn correctly in the folowing code, and not give spurious warnings.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void
takes_a_long  ( long sad_story ) {
    printf("Long %lu\n", sad_story );
}

void
takes_a_float  ( float my_boat ) {
    printf("Float  %f\n", my_boat );
}

int
main (int argc, char **argv)  {

    float   my_boat     = 1.0f;
    long    sad_story   = 1.0L;

    // No warnings wanted
    takes_a_float (my_boat);
    takes_a_long (sad_story);

    // Warnings required
    takes_a_long  (my_boat);
    takes_a_float (sad_story);

    exit (0);
}
```

**Edit 2**

The real solution is to upgrade my compiler. Not something the company is willing to do for complicated reasons (sigh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess from the info pages, did you try `-Wno-traditional-conversion`?

Edit: I checked, and it works, but sadly, this works with gcc 4.3 and newer only. From gcc 4.1 man page, it seems your observed behaviour is what `-Wconversion` was supposed to do in older versions, and it doesn't warn on a normal `double -> float` conversion.

Comment: I tried it just now. Doesn't help. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: All I have to do now is convince 3 layers of management in a different branch of the company to upgrade our compiler. :-(. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Couldn't you just compile the code with gcc 4.3 for the sake of the transition, and then continue using your old compiler for production?

Comment: +1 For a commentary on the `-Wconversion` change in meaning in gcc 4.3, see http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/NewWconversion.

Answer (score 3):

From the [manpage](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.6/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wconversion-248) (also at http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2008/Jul/msg00720.html):

> **-Wconversion**
>
> Warn if a prototype causes a type conversion that is
>   different from what would happen to
>   the same argument in the absence of a
>   prototype.  This includes conversions
>   of fixed point to floating and vice
>   versa, and conversions changing the
>   width or signedness of a fixed point
>   argument except when the same as the
>   default promotion.

So, the warning is performing exactly as documented. If you'd like to check specifically for some conversions, you could try turning on `-Wconversion` on a single run, logging that to a file, and searching for `long` -> `float` conversions.

---

This option is apparently intended for use in porting traditional C to ISO/ANSI C.

Comment: It's not the same as what the most recent documentation says; http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.3/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options.

Comment: You're using GCC 3.4.6, so you'll want *that* version of the manpage: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.6/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options

Answer (score 2):

I believe the flag you are most likely looking for is **`-Wall`** which you may wish to combine with **`-std=XX`** where XX is one of (c89|gnu89|c99|gnu99|...), and/or possibly **`-pedantic`** which is even more annoying pedantic (or more an*lly retentive depending on your mood :)

BTW, you forgot to include stdlib.h (for exit() prototype.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void takes_a_float ( float some_num ) {
    printf("float Hello %f\n", some_num );
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)  {
   float my_boat = 1.0;
   takes_a_float (  my_boat );
   exit( 0 );
}
```

and my console output:

---

```
mctaylor@tigger:stackoverflow$ gcc -Wall -pedantic long_float.c -o long_float
mctaylor@tigger:stackoverflow$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: i486-linux-gnu
...
gcc version 4.3.2 (Ubuntu 4.3.2-1ubuntu12)
```

---

Using **-Wall -pedantic** forces you to write clean, explicit code, and can help you catch a lot of potential silly mistakes. Good luck.

I wonder if the "missing warning" messages might be because of C type promotion rules. (See K&R The C Programming Language, 2nd ed, section 2.7 - *Type Conversion*). Just food for thought.

I hope this helps.

**EDITED to add additional material** (which follows):

Another option or approach is [splint](http://www.splint.org/)  (Secure Programming Lint) or [Gimple Software](http://www.gimpel.com/)'s PC-lint / FlexLint whuch are [lint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_programming_tool) implementations of a static analysis of C source code that flags *suspicious and non-portable constructs.*

---

```
mctaylor@tigger:stackoverflow$ splint sad_story.c 
Splint 3.1.2 --- 07 May 2008

sad_story.c: (in function takes_a_long)
sad_story.c:5:26: Format argument 1 to printf (%lu) expects unsigned long int
                     gets long int: sad_story
  To ignore signs in type comparisons use +ignoresigns
   sad_story.c:5:20: Corresponding format code
sad_story.c: (in function main)
sad_story.c:21:18: Function takes_a_long expects arg 1 to be long int gets
                      float: my_boat
  To allow all numeric types to match, use +relaxtypes.
sad_story.c:22:19: Function takes_a_float expects arg 1 to be float gets long
                      int: sad_story
sad_story.c:12:15: Parameter argc not used
  A function parameter is not used in the body of the function. If the argument
  is needed for type compatibility or future plans, use /*@unused@*/ in the
  argument declaration. (Use -paramuse to inhibit warning)
sad_story.c:12:28: Parameter argv not used
sad_story.c:4:6: Function exported but not used outside sad_story: takes_a_long
  A declaration is exported, but not used outside this module. Declaration can
  use static qualifier. (Use -exportlocal to inhibit warning)
   sad_story.c:6:1: Definition of takes_a_long
sad_story.c:8:6: Function exported but not used outside sad_story:
                    takes_a_float
   sad_story.c:10:1: Definition of takes_a_float

Finished checking --- 7 code warnings
```

---

You can also try the example in FlexLint at Gimpel's [Online Testing](http://www.gimpel-online.com/OnlineTesting.html) which is cleaner and pretty output.

Comment: I like to add -Wextra , also.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get this warning, I guess it's because I'm using a more recent version of GCC (4.3.3).